# Programming with or in Java

Tags: prepositions

I'm a software programmer and writing a CV in English now. How can I describe my experience correctly?

programming IN Java
or
programming WITH Java

Java is a programming language.

Comment: I would say you program **in** a language **with** and IDE or tools suite.  E.g., I have experience programming in Java with NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

The following distinction is subtle and may not make a difference.

**Programming with Java** has a broader (perhaps more sophisticated) tone. "I completed the project programming with Java and Soap."

**Programming in Java** has a more direct and deep, but narrow tone: "I just finished the Java class at the University, and now I know how to program in Java." Also, "I know how to program in Java."

Using Google Search, **Programming with Java** is the more common phrase, by an order of magnitude, even in web page titles:

- Google Search: ["intitle:Programming with Java"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22programming+in+java%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS550US550&oq=%22programming+in+java%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8161j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=intitle%3a%22programming+with+java%22) = 263,000
- Google Search: ["intitle:Programming in Java"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22programming+in+java%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS550US550&oq=%22programming+in+java%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8161j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=intitle%3a%22programming+in+java%22) = 22,000
- Google Search: ["Programming with Java"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22programming+in+java%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS550US550&oq=%22programming+in+java%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8161j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=%22programming+with+java%22) = 6,000,000
- Google Search: ["Programming in Java"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22programming+in+java%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS550US550&oq=%22programming+in+java%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8161j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) = 800,000

With this said, CV questions are extremely context dependent.

As a bullet point accomplishment:

> - **Programming with Java and Net Beans**, culminating in a successful launch for a top tier product for a Fortune 500 company.

As a bullet point skill:

> - Programming Languages: Java, C#, C++

Prose limited to programming language skill:

> - I have experience **programming in Java**, C#, and C++.

Note the ways "with" can produce a broader (more sophisticated) tone:
I worked in/with several groups to get the job done.
I worked in/with the marketing team to create a successful launch.